# Windows 8 and Ubuntu OS installation possible on the same computer?

Tags: 13.10, windows, uninstall, system-installation, data-recovery

I have a simple question: "If I install Ubuntu 13.10 on my Windows 8 PC and lets say I need/want to go back to Windows 8, could I use recovery discs to remove Ubuntu and simply reinstall Windows"?

Also I really would like to play my steam games on Ubuntu, but they are all Windows games, so is there any way I could install Windows steam games on Ubuntu 13.10? I'd rather not have to dual-boot and switch between OS platforms to just play my games.

**Specs**:

- HP pavilion G6
- 4gb ram (soon to be 8gb)
- AMD graphics card

Answer (score 0):

if you have the install discs and the Windows CD key, reinstalling Windows back onto the PC would be simple.

As for the games, I believe that a couple of the Valve Source games are available natively on Linux, as well as a few other miscellaneous games.  Though, most games aren't compatible or you would need to run through Wine, but that's not saying that they would run properly.

Comment: Well if my PC came with windows 8 already installed in it can i use the product code from pc info and the use recovery discs? or do i need a installation disc?

Comment: could I use recovery discs?